# Why does interface implementation in Emit with explicit overload behave different for public and non-public?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit

I've been working with Reflection.Emit for a long time, but this time it just doesn't make sense... Somewhere in my program, I'm implementing interfaces using emit. E.g.:

```
typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(intf);
```

Because I'm implementing multiple interfaces and interfaces can inherit from other interfaces, I de-duplicate methods/interfaces. (While it isn't related here I'm going to use some well-known interfaces for my examples). For example, if I implement both IList and IDictionary they both implement ICollection and I only implement ICollection once.

Afterwards, I start adding methods to the typeBuilder using the resulting list of methods and interface. Nothing fancy, just:

```
MethodBuilder mb = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
    name,
    MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.Virtual |
    MethodAttributes.Final | specialAttributes, CallingConventions.HasThis,
    returnType,
    parameterTypes);

// [...] emit code that doesn't really matter here

typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(mb, baseMethodFromInterface);
```

Notice that I explicitly define the method override. I do this because names might clash, f.ex. in the above example both IList and ICollection expose a Count getter (name = get_Count), which will result in a name clash.

Let's now assume I use the name 'Count' while generating methods. As I noticed earlier, there are a couple of interfaces that derive from IList that implement this property. What I'm confused about is that apparently now 'Count' implicitly inherits from other Count methods as well - even if I don't define it as Override... but only if I expose the property as public. (e.g. specialAttributes = MethodAttributes.Public). What happens is that PEVerify will give an error, but the code will run just fine:

```
[IL]: Error: [c:\tmp\emit\Test.dll : Test::get_Count][offset 0x00000012] Method is not visible.
```

To solve this, I tried to change specialAttributes = MethodAttributes.Private - but because of a minor bug, I haven't implemented all Count things explicitly (using DefineMethodOverride). Strangely enough, CreateType now tells me that "Count [...] does not have an implementation." - e.g. it cannot find a method of Count that acts as override.

However, since I'm using DefineMethodOverride I'm wondering why it worked in the first place? In other words: the 'Private' errors make sense, the fact that it worked when using public methods do not IMO.

So for my questions: Why does .NET implicitly override public methods with the same name even if you *explicitly* define the override as an override for another method (this sounds to me like a bug in .NET...)? Why does this work? And why does PEVerify give the error when you expose the methods as public?

**update**

Apparently the PEVerify error is unrelated: after making everything private and implementation of all methods explicit, PEVerify is still giving the same error. The error has to do with calling the wrong method, e.g.:

```
// Incorrect: attempt to call a private member -> PEVerify error
callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, int32>::System.Collections.IDictionary.Remove(object)

// Correct: call the interface using a vtable lookup
callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.Collections.IList::Remove(object)
```

Still, this was merely a sidetrack, the questions remain.

**Update +1**

I've made what I consider a minimal testcase. This basically generates a DLL that you should inspect with your favorite tool. Note that I only implement 1 method here, not 2 (!) The second method is overridden 'automagically', even though I explicitly tell .NET that the method implements the first method.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int First();
    int Second();
}

public class FooGenerator
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateClass();
    }

    public static void CreateClass()
    {
        // Create assembly
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("test_emit.dll");
        var assemblyBuilder =
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName,
            AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave, @"c:\tmp");

        // Create module
        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("test_emit", "test_emit.dll", false);

        // Create type : IFoo
        var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("TestClass", TypeAttributes.Public);
        typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IFoo));

        ConstructorBuilder constructorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(
            MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig |
            MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName,
            CallingConventions.HasThis, Type.EmptyTypes);

        // Generate the constructor IL. 
        ILGenerator gen = constructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();

        // The constructor calls the constructor of Object
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructor(
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, Type.DefaultBinder, Type.EmptyTypes, null));
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // Add the 'Second' method
        var mb = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Second",
            MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.Virtual |
            MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.HasThis,
            typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes);

        // Implement
        gen = mb.GetILGenerator();

        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(mb, typeof(IFoo).GetMethod("First"));

        typeBuilder.CreateType();
        assemblyBuilder.Save("test_emit.dll");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the behavior where you define a public method e.x. Count not the default behavior of .net when writing the same code in C#? If so, then you will need to do override for IList.Count and IDictionary.Count separately. I would guess by doing so, you should not have name conflict because IDictionary does not inherit IList so implementation would be different.

Comment: If you do it in C#, it doesn't add the DefineMethodOverride . If you implement them separately, I don't see a way to make them public. Still, there are other languages to consider, some of which might be able to override methods and give them a different name (which is valid!)

Comment: As kvb stated, You will have to use IList.Count and IDictionary.Count. You will define the method itself as public but you will specific the methodInfo for IList.Count and IDictionary.Count which are private. By doing so, you will only have access the Count for IList when the object is casted to IList since the override is explicit instead of implicit.

Comment: Yes I know the C# syntax, it just might not be a valid reason here. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride.aspx : It explicitly states "with a different name" without constraints. There's also Javascript, Python, Ruby, VB and a bunch of other languages to consider in .NET... I wouldn't be surprised if this constraint doesn't hold in all possible languages.

Comment: The scenario is perfectly valid. You defined Second Method, and called DefineOverride for First method. Second method should automatically override Second of interface and Second method definition will be used for First method override. So whatever code you emit in second will be reflected for first. The case is only valid because of the return type and parameter types are the same. This will not work for scenario where the return type and parameter types are different

Comment: Sorry for my asking, but I still don't see the logic of this. I see what happens and understand what happens, but want to understand the reasoning they had when they implemented this behavior in .NET (that's what I mean with 'why'): The only thing I can see is that it will yield unexpected results when your interface changes (to be precise: when you add a method with the same signature). For example when we were using methods named `Name` and `Alias` instead of `First` and `Second` and `Alias` is added in a later version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple methods with the same name and signature, then your type is not valid.  If you want to explicitly implement an interface, then typically you would use private methods that have different names (e.g. the C# compiler uses something like `IList.Count` instead of `Count`).

**UPDATE**

After your update I now see that I had the diagnosis somewhat backwards.  If a class is declared as implementing an interface and there is an interface method with no matching method override then the CLR will search for a method with the same name and signature.  There is no way to tell the CLR not to do this (other than providing a different specific override for that interface method), and the same concrete method can override multiple interface methods, by design.  Likewise, it would be perfectly fine for your concrete method to be called `Third` and to explicitly override both `First` and `Second`.

**UPDATE 2**

I'll attempt to answer your other question, but "why" questions are always hard.  First of all, adding a method to an interface is a serious breaking change and should basically never happen - if you add a new method to your interface then you would expect all classes that implement that interface (which might be developed by third parties if your interface is public) will break since they claim to implement the interface but are missing a method.

There seems to be little downside to being able to override multiple interface methods with a single concrete implementation.  Typically those methods would be from different interfaces, so this would be a convenient way to avoid having to create multiple implementations that are identical (supposing that the different interface methods have identical semantics, so that overriding them via a single method makes sense).  Likewise, it's convenient for the CLR to look for methods via name+signature rather than requiring an explicit mapping.  Your case is basically a very weird corner case instance of these more general mechanisms, where multiple methods from the same interface are being implemented by one slot, once via an explicit override and once via the default lookup.  This is very strange, it doesn't seem like it's worth it for the CLR to explicitly look out for this particular scenario, especially given that it would be unlikely (or impossible) to generate from C# source.

Comment: While you have a point, I'm having trouble with this answer. There's more than C# to consider here... And in IL it's perfectly legal to give your overload another name in IL, e.g. you might name IList.Count something else like -well- IsReadOnly with a DefineMethodOverride that tells .NET that it's an override of IList.Count :-) If someone decides to add another property to IList (IsReadOnly), you would expect the code not to compile - but in fact it will! If memory serves, you can even define multiple methods with the same name and signature in IL, as long as they have different return types.

Comment: I was talking about the IL level, not C#: you cannot have two methods with the same name and signature in a type, or the type is malformed (and return type counts as part of the signature).  You are right that methods can have arbitrary names and still override interface methods with different names.  Indeed, that is what I'm suggesting you need to implement (name your override `"IList.Count"` instead of just `"Count"`).

Comment: Ah yes, that's correct, we agree on that. That means my issue is that if I have `IList::Count` and implement that as MyType::IsReadOnly with an explicit `DefineMethodOverride`, I don't see why it would also implicitly override `IList::IsReadOnly` as well -- after all, that's not what I specified. (assuming it has the same signature of course)... So apparently `DefineMethodOverride` only _includes_ an override, but doesn't _exclude_ all others, which I find heavily debatable behavior for the reason that this might break stuff if the interface changes. So why does this happen?

Comment: To be honest, without a repro it's hard to even understand what behavior you're actually observing, not to mention why you're observing it.  It would be greatly helpful if you could just create a simple self-contained example of the problems you're seeing.

Comment: I added a minimal self-contained testcase that shows what happens. If it's not clear, please let me know.

Comment: Great - that helps a lot.  See if my update answers your question.

Comment: Ah it does add, I wasn't aware that you can introduce a `Third` that inherits from both `First` and `Second`. +1 for that and for the in-depth answers. Still, I'm looking for the "why": isn't this dangerous? If `IFoo` at first only has `First` implemented and later on we added a method `Second`, I would have expected my emitted code to break - while this shows it doesn't. That can result in unexpected behavior. The only workaround is to make overrides private. So while it's clear from the testcase *that* it works like this, I would like to understand **why** it is designed like this?

Comment: Hmm sorry... Perhaps my use of the word 'why' is somewhat vague... what I'm trying to understand is "why the guys at Microsoft designed it like this", the part "why this works" is solved.

Comment: Okay, I've added some more thoughts.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer. You're right that this is indeed a corner case and impossible to generate from C#. So rare, that it probably wasn't worth checking... simply because it's so rare that the behavior doesn't really matter, as long as it's always the same. Thanks for the insightful discussion, I enjoyed it.